# How to set `aria-disabled` as true using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea about JS. But there is needed one line of code in my Ruby. I have the below `html`.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
      <button class="otherButtonClass ui-state-hover ui-state-focus" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <button class="otherButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">
      <button class="cancelButtonClass" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want JS code to make the first and second button to make them visible. What would be the code?

Please help.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI for the buttons? Then it's just `$(".otherButtonClass").show().button("enable");`

Comment: @Bergi did you see jQuery tag here?

Comment: @jQuery00: No, but lot's of jQueryUI-like classes. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Do note that you should not be using either `role="button"` or the `aria-disabled` attribute on `button` elements of type `button`. `role="button"` is automatic. Use `disabled`, not `aria-disabled` for the attribute. See [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current way of setting `aria-` attributes is to reference the properties directly.

To get:

```
let el = document.getElementById('foobar');
console.log(el.ariaDisabled); // Should log the current value of aria-disabled.
```

To set:

```
let el = document.getElementById('foobar');
el.ariaDisabled = 'true';
console.log(el.ariaDisabled); // Should log 'true'.
```

Reference: [Element.ariaDisabled MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaDisabled)

Comment: not supported by FireFox yet

Answer (score 23):

http://jsfiddle.net/SQ7SH/1/

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.ui-dialog-buttonset button');
    buttons[0].setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
    buttons[1].setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
```

Also button require close tag

Answer (score 2):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButtonClass');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
}
```

Comment: Better use the string `"true"` instead of `true`

Comment: Because it is casted to a string anyway. Attributes do only store string values.

Answer (score 1):

As asked `there is needed one line of code`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ui-dialog-buttonset .otherButtonClass').forEach(function (item) {item.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);});
```